# How is print statement showing one thing and unit test result showing another using same array as input for the same method?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, pytest

```
import unittest
import Root

class TestRoot(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_timeOperation(self):
        timesAA = ['07:15','07:45','06:12','06:32','12:01','13:16']
        result = Root.timeOperation(timesAA)
        self.assertEqual(result, [1800,1200,4500])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

[Result from unit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i64lj.png)

```
def timeOperation(drivenTime2):
    for x in range(0, len(drivenTime2)-1, 2):
        #converts string objects in the array into time objects
        time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(drivenTime2[x], '%H:%M')
        time3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(drivenTime2[x+1], '%H:%M')
        #calculates time dureation and converts to seconds
        durationInSeconds = (time3 - time2).total_seconds()
        durationArray.append(durationInSeconds)
    return durationArray


timesA = ['07:15','07:45','06:12','06:32','12:01','13:16']

print(timeOperation(timesA))
```

[Result from print statement in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee4kw.png)

Comment: Can you write the full question on here. Those pictures might not always be available.

Comment: Your `durationsArray` is a global variable, meaning that it will accumulate the results of running `timeOperation`. You can test that by executing it multiple times in a row: `print(timeOperation(timesA)); print(timeOperation(timesA))` etc. You will see that the returned result gets longer with each print. Move `durationsArray = []` into the `timeOperation` function to fix this.

Comment: You are right on hoefling...Thanks a bunch!